# How to use UITextField to input information to UITableView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to make a ToDo list app and I can't for the life of me seem to figure out how to make the text box's typed text go into a box with a tick box for me to be able to change to completed.

Can anyone help me? I am just getting started in Xcode so please explain why/how it works that way I can learn for the future. Thanks guys!

App Rendering (What I am trying to make)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wU3B.jpg

Currently in Xcode (What I have so far)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8cj2.jpg

Comment: So far I haven't tried anything too major. I tried to follow a tutorial on adding an item to the Table but it used a notification alert to input it and couldn't get it to relate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an IBAction for add button. So its get called when you click the button and store the entered text in UItextfield in an array and you will use that array to add rows in your table.

For example consider the code :

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
       return [dataArray count];
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
      if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
      }
      [cell.textLabel setText: [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      return cell;
    }


    -(IBAction)addCity:(id)sender
    {
      [tableView beginUpdates];
      [dataArray addObject:@"City"];
      NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[dataArray count]-1 inSection:1]];
      [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
      [tableView endUpdates];
   }
```

Comment: Where should this go? In the .h or the .m under the @implementation? I have everything set up in the .xib but nothing is coded in. Here is an image of my .h. http://gyazo.com/c3e1acda7abaf648115f1e7d7e7d578d and here is an image of my .m http://gyazo.com/8cc8c995edfe9add339184a508e1fcb7

Comment: Hey first get your basic clear. Go through basic tutorials of creating  UITableView, UIButton, UITextField and all. How to create IBAction and Property of those and their methods and delegates.
Check this link for tutorials http://www.raywenderlich.com

Comment: that code will go in .m under @implementation
You need to create IBAction of ADD UIButton, referencing outlet of UITableView & UITextField.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend you check out the free Sensible TableView framework. The framework should help you automatically create your text fields and automatically fill/save their data.

Comment: Would this allow me to add the UI Customization to make it look like my rendering? I am trying to make it exactly like my Photoshop Rendering.

Comment: Yeah I believe they have CSS-like theme styling where you could style your app in any way you wish.